# Get the date of a time by different timezone?

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

The following code will return the correct date by timezone. `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId` is not faster enough in my case. Is it a faster way?

```
// Return the date part of t by tz
DateTime GetDateByTZ(DateTimeOffset t, string tz)
{
    return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(t, tz).Date;
}

var t1 = DateTimeOffset.Parse("1/17/2020 21:00 -5");
GetDateByTZ(t1, 'GMT Standard Time') // returns 2020-1-18
```

I need a super faster version of `GetDateByTZ`.

I found that use `t.AddHours(...).Date` is much faster but then I will need to maintain an hour offset lookup table, plus the logic for daylight savings changes (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time).

For example, if I'm in London, I can call `DateTime.Now.AddHours(-5).Date` to get the date of "East Standard time". However, I will need to change -5 to -4 in summer.

Comment: Very confused, what's your question

Comment: Why do you think it is not fast enough? What benchmarks have you run?

Comment: If you have a complex date / timezone problem, Noda Time (nodatime.org) is often part of the solution

Comment: Also, which .NET runtime are you using? And are you passing the same time zone ID every time, or different ones?

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint, it takes about 2 seconds for 10M calls.

Comment: That doesn't sound all that bad really.  Besides, you're in the realm of microbenchmarking.  You really should be using https://benchmarkdotnet.org/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure we have enough information from you (see comments on your question), but I'll point out that this:

```
DateTimeOffset result = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(dateTimeOffset, timeZoneId)
```

... is equivalent to this:

```
TimeZoneInfo tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneId);
DateTimeOffset result = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dateTimeOffset, tzi);
```

Thus if you are repeatedly working with the same zone, you can get slightly better results by looking up the `TimeZoneInfo` object *once* and holding on to it for reuse in future conversions.

I say only *slightly* faster, because both `FindSystemTimeZoneById` and `ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId` use an internal cache.  So you're not reducing allocations, just the time it takes to look up the item from the cache.

Comment: This is _still_ looks like a micro optimization to me, honestly. In real life, do we ever need a faster solution for this scenario? Maybe some academic/scientific research? Meh, I don't know. OP should [race his/her horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) first in my opinion to know which way is faster :)